# Advice on DB Table Structure for Message System

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have not found a tutorial yet on the internet for what I am looking for. 
Functionality I am after is a simple message send and retrieve function.

1. User 1 - Sends Message to User 2
2. User 2 can view messages in their Inbox

I know I will need 2 controllers one for Handling the message sending and the other to retrieve.

How would this type of system function on the DB side. Do i make a new Table for Inbox and so all messages are sent there with corresponding id of sender and receiver?

Comment: This is not a good StackOverflow question. Generally you should have already attempted something or at least considered a few options. Wondering about how to complete a task or _what is the best way to complete a task_ given a few options is a completely different thing. Any person trying to answer your question will have to explain many concepts while in reality you might only need help on a specific decision. Please take this as an advice, I have not downvoted your question but I believe you can ask a better question next time. :)

Comment: Well I guess I could attempt a theory first and see how it goes. I just didn't know what would be the optimal way of building this.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble figuring out? Is it what tables you're going to need? How to implement the server side? Depending on your answer to this I can give you some more advice :)

Comment: My issue is the table structure. And if polling the database is the efficient way to go for a large scale app to give a realtime effect.

Comment: Ah, so you see that the question isn't relevant to AngularJS. You can edit the question (most importantly, the tags) in order to ask for advice on how to build the table structure, and I will also try to answer it as best as I can.

Answer (score 1):

A simple 2 tables should be enough for this:

```
TblUsers (UserId, UserName, Password, FirstName, LastName)

TblMessages (FromUser [fk to tblUsers], ToUser [fk to tblUsers], Title, Content, SentDate, ReadDate, DeletedDate)
```

Note the DeletedDate is only relevant if you want to enable a recycle bin for messages.

If you want to enable sending the same messages to multiple users, you need a little different schema:

```
TblMessags(MessageId, FromUser [fk to tblUsers], Title, Content, SentDate)

TblRecipients(MessageId [fk to messages], RecipientId [fk to users], ReadDate, DeletedDate)
```

Comment: Sorry what do you mean about fk to tblUsers?

Comment: [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) and [that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you require help with the table structure and not with the implementation itself, here is a possible scenario:

1. A table for all users
2. A table for all messages

Keep in mind that the `users` table and the `messages` table is up to you define the attributes you want to store in them. An initial approach could be:

```
CREATE TABLE users(userID int, username VARCHAR(30));
CREATE TABLE messages(messageID int, senderID int, recipientID int, title VARCHAR(50), content VARCHAR(1000));
```

Getting a specific user's Inbox could then be done using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE messages.recipientID=XXXX
```

`XXXX` is of course the userID of the user's inbox you want. This would only get the message data. If you wanted to display the sender data you could join the result of the previous query with a query for `senderID` or `recipientID`.

---

Table structure can be changed according to what type of queries you're anticipating. I believe this should suffice as an initial approach, and then you can analyse whether you need to group or index data that gets requested a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I make a new Table for Inbox and so all messages are sent there with corresponding id of sender and receiver?

Basically, yes.

I realize that you want to build a simple message table with one sender and one receiver.  You might as well design the tables for one sender and multiple receivers, in case you want to expand your message system.

Let's make the user table.

```
User
----
User ID
User Name
...
```

And the message table.

```
Message
-------
Message ID
Message Sent Time Stamp
Message Text
```

A user can send more than one message and receive more than one message.  So, we build a junction table.

```
MessageUser
-----------
Message ID
User ID
Sender / Receiver Flag
...
```

The primary key is (Message ID, User ID).  You will also have a unique index on (User ID, Message ID).  The primary key allows you to get a message to the user.  The unique index allows you to build a list of previous messages for a user.